# Expected value of the floor function of a sum of two variables

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, expectation, uniform-distribution

In a recently published paper I have encountered the following equality. Let $U$ be a random variable uniformly distributed in $[0,1]$ and let $Z$ be a Gaussian variable with mean zero and standard deviation $\sigma$. Let $\lfloor x\rfloor$
be the floor function and let $\left\{x\right\}=x-\lfloor x\rfloor$ be the fractional part of x.
I want to show that

$$
\mathbb{E}\left[\lfloor U+Z\rfloor^2\mid Z\right] = \left(Z-\left\{Z\right\}\right)^2\,\left(1-\left\{Z\right\}\right)+\left(Z+1-\left\{Z\right\}\right)^2\,\left\{Z\right\}. 
$$

In order to prove the above equality I have tried to use

$$
\lfloor U+Z\rfloor^2\ = \left(U+Z-\left\{U+Z\right\}\right)^2 = U^2+Z^2+2\,U\,Z+\left\{U+Z\right\}^2-2\,\left(U+Z\right)\,\left\{U+Z\right\}
$$

and the fact that the expected value is conditioned on the value of $Z$, but unfortunately I am not able to exactly recover the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can assume the variables are independent, is that right?

We know that $U$ is distributed uniformly on $[0,1]$. 
For a given value of $Z$, then, $U + Z$ is uniformly distributed on $[Z, Z+1].$ But
$$[Z, Z+1] = [Z, \lfloor Z + 1 \rfloor] \cup [\lfloor Z + 1 \rfloor, Z + 1]$$
and the size of $[\lfloor Z + 1 \rfloor, Z + 1]$ is
$$(Z + 1) - \lfloor Z + 1 \rfloor = \{Z\},$$
so
$$P(\lfloor U + Z \rfloor = \lfloor Z + 1 \rfloor\mid Z) = P(U + Z \ge \lfloor Z + 1 \rfloor\mid Z) = \{Z\}$$
and
$$P(\lfloor U + Z \rfloor = \lfloor Z \rfloor\mid Z) = P(U + Z < \lfloor Z + 1 \rfloor\mid Z) = 1 - \{Z\}.$$
That's the entire probability distribution of $\lfloor U + Z \rfloor,$ so we can easily find the distribution of $\lfloor U + Z \rfloor^2$ and compute its expectation directly.

Comment: Thanks, this sounds simply and correct. Perhaps you mean $P\left(\lfloor U+Z\rfloor=\lfloor Z+1 \rfloor\right)=...$ and $P\left(\lfloor U+Z\rfloor=\lfloor Z \rfloor\right)=...$ instead of $P\left(\lfloor U+Z\rfloor= Z+1\right)=...$ and $P\left(\lfloor U+Z\rfloor=Z\right)=...$, resp.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I have applied it to the answer.